# Sum of the given series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image]

I don't how to start here. Please provide some hint for initial step.

Comment: What happens when we add the 2 series together?

Comment: @Element118 Not getting anything fruitful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have:

$$\frac{\pi^2}{6} = 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{16} + \dots$$

and let the other one have value $s$:

$$s = -1 + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{16} - \dots$$

Now by adding the two equations:

$$\frac{\pi^2}{6} + s = 2\Big[ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{36} + \frac{1}{64} + \dots \Big]$$

$$= \frac{1}{2}\Big[ 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{16} + \dots \Big]$$

Can you determine $s$ from here?